# stop and start execution of extension on certain website

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make an ad blocking extension. Here is the code:

Manifest.json:

```
    {
   "manifest_version":2,
   "name":"Ad Killer",
   "description":"A Basic program for blocking ads",
   "version":"0.7",
   "permissions": ["activeTab"],
   "background":{
      "scripts":[
      "background.js"]
   },
   "content_scripts":[
      {
         "matches":[
            "<all_urls>"
         ],

         "run_at" :"document_end",

         "js":[
            "jquery-3.2.1.min.js",
            "content.js"
         ]
      }
   ],
   "applications":{
      "gecko":{
         "id":"{99f660be-10c4-4cc8-9205-72dd45f156b9}"
      }
   },
   "browser_action":{
      "default_icon":"ad128.png",
      "default_title":"Ad Killer"
   }
}
```

Content.js:

```
/*var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");*/
var ob2 = $("div[class^='OB_AR_'],div[id*='OB_AR_']");
var ob3 = $("div[id^='outbrain_widget_13'],div[id*='outbrain_']");
var elems2 =  $("div[id^='taboola-'],div[id*='taboola']");
var elems3 =  $("div[id^='hireme'],div[id*='hireme']");
var elems4 =  $("div[id^='yandex'],div[id*='yandex']");
var banner = $("div[id^='rc-'],div[id*='rc-']");
var makeSure = $("div[id^='ad'],div[id*='ad']");
var fkn = $("div[class^='OUTBRAIN'],div[class*='outbrain']");
var yandex1 = $("div[id^='Ya_'],div[id*='ya']");
var ob11 = $("div[id^='adzerk'],div[id*='adzerk']");
var ob4 = $("div[class^='str-adunit str-adunit-mid-article str-card-exp str-collapsed clickout'],div[class*='str-adunit str-adunit-mid-article str-card-exp str-collapsed clickout']");
var trendTags = $("div[class^='trendingTags span-12'],div[class*='trendingTags span-12']");
var bank = $("div[class^='post postFill post-http://www.thejournal.ie/switching-banks-questions-department-of-finance-3355404-Apr2017/'],div[class*='post postFill post-http://www.thejournal.ie/switching-banks-questions-department-of-finance-3355404-Apr2017/']");
var google_ads = $("div[id^='google_ads_iframe_'],div[id*='google_ads_iframe_']");
var tennis1 = $("div[id^='ads'],div[id*='ads']");
var macaron = $("td[class^='marconi'],td[class*='marconi']");
var adidas = $("div[class^='GoogleActiveViewClass'],div[class*='GoogleActiveViewClass']");
var tel = $("div[class^='left-col'],div[class*='left-col']");
var aside = $("section[class^='zn zn-sponsored-outbrain-3 zn-balanced zn--idx-2 zn--ordinary zn-has-two-containers'],section[class^='zn zn-sponsored-outbrain-3 zn-balanced zn--idx-2 zn--ordinary zn-has-two-containers'");
var rh = document.getElementsByTagName("aside");
var adContent = $("div[id^='ad_'], iframe[id*='ad']");
var cloudfront = $("img[src^='//d13dcw'], img[src*='//d13dcw']");
var sidebar = $("div[class^='sidebar'], div[class*='sidebar']");
var jacobs = $("div[id^='jpx-wp-layer-'], div[id*='jpx-wp-layer-]'");
var trc1 = $("div[id^='trc_wrapper'], div[id*='trc_wrapper']");
var mb = $("div[class^='module-body'], div[class*='module-body']");

function hideTRC() {
     for (var i = 0, max = trc1.length; i < max; i++) {
        trc1[i].hidden = true;
    };
}

function hideJacobs() {
     for (var i = 0, max = jacobs.length; i < max; i++) {
        sidebar[i].hidden = true;
    };
}

function hideSide() {
     for (var i = 0, max = sidebar.length; i < max; i++) {
        sidebar[i].hidden = true;
    };
}

function hideIframes() {
     for (var i = 0, max = elems.length; i < max; i++) {
        elems[i].hidden = true;
    };
}

function hideIframes2() {
     for (var i = 0, max = elems2.length; i < max; i++) {
        elems2[i].hidden = true;
    };
}

function hideIframes3() {
     for (var i = 0, max = elems3.length; i < max; i++) {
        elems3[i].hidden = true;
    };
}

function hideIframes4() {
     for (var i = 0, max = elems4.length; i < max; i++) {
        elems4[i].hidden = true;
    };
}

function hideBanner() {
     for (var i = 0, max = banner.length; i < max; i++) {
        banner[i].hidden = true;
    };
}
function makeSure1() {
     for (var i = 0, max = makeSure.length; i < max; i++) {
        makeSure[i].hidden = true;
    };
}

function hideFKN() {
     for (var i = 0, max = fkn.length; i < max; i++) {
        fkn[i].hidden = true;
    };
}

function hideYandex() {
     for (var i = 0, max = yandex1.length; i < max; i++) {
        yandex1[i].hidden = true;
    };
}

function hideOB1() {
     for (var i = 0, max = ob11.length; i < max; i++) {
        ob11[i].hidden = true;
    };
}

function hideOB2() {
     for (var i = 0, max = ob2.length; i < max; i++) {
        ob2[i].hidden = true;
    };

}

function hideOB3() {
     for (var i = 0, max = ob3.length; i < max; i++) {
        ob3[i].hidden = true;
    };

}

function hideOB4() {
     for (var i = 0, max = ob4.length; i < max; i++) {
        ob4[i].hidden = true;
    };

}

function hideTTags() {
     for (var i = 0, max = trendTags.length; i < max; i++) {
        trendTags[i].hidden = true;
    };

}

function hideBank() {
     for (var i = 0, max = bank.length; i < max; i++) {
        bank[i].hidden = true;
    };

}

function hideGAds() {
     for (var i = 0, max = google_ads.length; i < max; i++) {
        google_ads[i].hidden = true;
    };

}

function hideTennis() {
     for (var i = 0, max = tennis1.length; i < max; i++) {
        tennis1[i].hidden = true;
    };

}

function hideMacaron() {
     for (var i = 0, max = macaron.length; i < max; i++) {
        macaron[i].hidden = true;
    };

}

function hideAdidas() {
     for (var i = 0, max = adidas.length; i < max; i++) {
        adidas[i].hidden = true;
    };

}

function hideTel() {
     for (var i = 0, max = tel.length; i < max; i++) {
        tel[i].hidden = true;
    };

}

function hideRH() {
     for (var i = 0, max = rh.length; i < max; i++) {
        rh[i].hidden = true;
    };

}

function hideAside() {
     for (var i = 0, max = aside.length; i < max; i++) {
        aside[i].hidden = true;
    };

}

function hideG2() {
     for (var i = 0, max = google_ads2.length; i < max; i++) {
        google_ads2[i].hidden = true;
    };

}

function hideAdContent() {
     for (var i = 0, max = adContent.length; i < max; i++) {
        adContent[i].hidden = true;
    };

}

function hideCloud() {
     for (var i = 0, max = cloudfront.length; i < max; i++) {
        cloudfront[i].hidden = true;
    };

}

function hideMB() {
     for (var i = 0, max = mb.length; i < max; i++) {
        mb[i].hidden = true;
    };

}

$(document).ready(function() {
    //hideIframes();
    hideOB2();
    //hideIframes2();
    //hideIframes3();
    hideIframes4();
    hideBanner();
    makeSure1();
    hideFKN();
    hideYandex();
    hideOB1();
    hideOB4();
    hideTTags();
    hideBank();
    hideGAds();
    hideTennis();
    hideMacaron();
    hideAdidas();
    hideTel();
    hideRH();
    hideAside();
    hideAdContent();
    hideCloud();
    hideSide();
    hideJacobs();
    hideTRC();
    hideMB();
});

window.onload = function() {
     //hideIframes();
     hideOB2();
     //hideIframes2();
     //hideIframes3();
     hideIframes4();
     hideBanner();
     makeSure1();
     hideFKN();
     hideYandex();
     hideOB1();
     hideOB4();
     hideTTags();
     hideBank();
     hideGAds();
     hideTennis();
     hideMacaron();
     hideAdidas();
     hideTel();
     hideRH();
     hideAside();
     hideAdContent();
     hideCloud();
     hideSide();
     hideJacobs();
     hideTRC();
     hideMB();
};

$(window).on('load', function() {
    //hideIframes();
    hideOB2();
    //hideIframes2();
    //hideIframes3();
    hideIframes4();
    hideIframes();
    hideBanner();
    makeSure1();
    hideFKN();
    hideYandex();
    hideOB1();
    hideOB4();
    hideTTags();
    hideBank();
    hideGAds();
    hideTennis();
    hideMacaron();
    hideAdidas();
    hideTel();
    hideRH();
    hideAside();
    hideAdContent();
    hideCloud();
    hideSide();
    hideJacobs();
    hideTRC();
    hideMB();

});
/*
do {
    setTimeout(hideIframes, 3000); 
}
while (elems > 0);

if (elems > 0) {
    setTimeout(hideIframes, 3000); 
}

do {
    setTimeout(hideIframes3, 3000); 
    hideIframes3();
}
while (elems3 > 0);
*/
do {
    hideOB1();
}

while (ob11 > 0);

hideRH();
```

`restore.js` is practically `content.js` except all hidden attributes are `false`.

And background.js:

```
var enable = false;
enable = enable ? false : true;
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    enable = enable ? false : true;
    if(enable){
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({ text: 'ON' });
    //location.reload();
     chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: 'content.js' }); 
} else {
    enable = false;
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({ text: 'OFF' });
    //chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code:"location.reload(false);"});
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: 'restore.js' }); 
    }
});
```

This all compiles fine, but I want to do 1 thing. Every time the user visits the new tab page(`chrome://newtab`) I want the script to stop running and change the toggle status to OFF. And whenever the extension is in a website, I would like it to be ON as default. Does anyone know how to achieve this. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Dont repeat yourself... Dont repeat yourself... Dont repeat yourself...

Comment: @JonasW. sorry sir :). Do you know how to fix the problem at hand

Comment: on a side note, look into how arrays work. You have a ton of code duplication

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ActiveTab Permission](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab) to access current focused Tab and eventually test tab Url/hostname against the website you need, then take action accordingly .
**NB: using "all_urls" is a bad habit** another solution is using ["tabs"](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs)
and once you list exact url/website permissions, your extension will only be activated on tabs with given urls.